# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' while Invoke

Tags: c#, invoke, dispatcher

I get `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'` error while:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Delegate)(() =>
            {
                this.Focus();
                if (!moveFocus)
                    return;
                this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[0]);
```

I looked up all posts about it, but i couldn't figure out/understand why? and the answers didnt solve my problem as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda expressions cannot be cast to `Delegate` directly. However, if the method expects a delegate of a certain type (e.g. `Action`), then you can use the lambda expression without casting. For example, in **.Net 4.5** there exists a overload of:

```
public void Invoke(Action callback,DispatcherPriority priority)
```

this means you can do this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            //...
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

but that overload does not exist in .Net 4 or prior. So you would have to cast to an `Action`:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        ...
    }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Note that I removed the `new object[0]`. It's not needed as `Action` doesn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Don't cast to `Delegate` but to `Action`:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            ...
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[0]);
```

Comment: Ok that's weird because when i used `new Action` it didn't work either but `(Action)` worked!! Anyways could please explain why not using `Delegate`?

Comment: `new Action` does the same. Works here too: `Invoke(new Action(() =>`.

Comment: You could write some extension methods to allow `Invoke(() =>` to work.

Comment: I know it should work but it doesn't, probably bugged/needs restart. and yes i could, but no need to it's just the same

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to cast to delegate lambda expression implicitly casted by  the compiler  to  a delegate type

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.Focus();
                if (!moveFocus)
                    return;
                this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: Doesn't work: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: yes  it  does if you omit new  Object[0] which does not make sense here

Comment: @ErenErsönmez that's true I suppose  what the OP is using actually